# How to simulate state using immutable javascript

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

#### //REVISION 1

Instead of building a commandline plugin (which gets a new environment state, and so the function itself cannot retain state @T.J. Crowder)
, suppose I was building a simple function to be called in a script.

Simple example: (The Counter Plugin) I would like the plugin to increment one every time it is run.

ie.

```
console.log(counter())
    -> 1
console.log(counter())
    -> 2
```

I assume that the answer has something to do with a recursive loop, but I do not understand how would one achieve this?

My best guess is that it looks something like this:

```
export function counter(){
    return counter
}
```

---

#### //FIRST VERSION

I am building a commandline node plugin with immutablejs.

Simple example: (The Counter Plugin) I would like the plugin to increment one every time it is run.

ie.

```
$ node bin/counter
-> 1
$ node bin/counter
-> 2
```

I assume that the answer has something to do with a recursive loop, but I do not understand how would one achieve this?

My best guess is that it looks something like this:

```
export function counter(){
    return counter
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*simulating* state"?

Comment: If you need to persist state between `node` invocations (in contrast to something like running a repl in one process), then you'll need to store it somewhere like in a file.

Comment: I just mean that the counter function knows the result from the previous time it was run. (Is that state?)

Comment: could you tell **why** do you want to do it?

Comment: Because I'm trying to create a purely functional javascript plugin.

Comment: Does `var num=0; function counter() { return num++; } module.exports = counter;` do what you're after? Not entirely clear how permanent you expect your number to be

Comment: @smokeyPHP thats cheating ;)

Comment: Or you can look into [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the answer has something to do with a recursive loop...

No, this has nothing to do with recursion.

You'd need to have the "plugin" store its state somewhere, since every time it's run via `node`, it gets a completely new global environment.

So it might store that data in a file, for instance.

Comment: suppose that it was a globally installed node package, would that make a difference?

Comment: @l2silver: No, it still gets an entirely new global environment when it's run, just like any other program does.